# "initWithNibName" method not being called

Tags: cocoa-touch

```
NSString *nibName = @"SampleViewController"
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
```

using the above code to move to the "SampleViewController" xib... its working fine but `initWithNibName` method not triggering in the `SampleViewController`.
 anyone can help me to trigger lifecycle method in `SampleViewController`

Comment: Did you try this ?   SampleViewController *viewController = [[SampleViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Comment: You need to call it an on object of the type `SampleViewController`, so do `[SampleViewController alloc]` instead of on an `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIViewController is parent from which SampleViewController is implemented. So instead of UIViewController you need to use SampleViewController class instance.

```
SampleViewController *controller = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SampleViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: thank you very much for your quick reply I am using sliding menu to navigate view controller. sliding menu info coming from PList in the Plist i have added 3 string items (Id,DisplayName,nibName) when i click the menu item. get the nib name and try to load view controller according to the nib name string.

Comment: If you will do the way you was doing, you will not be able to access specific members of that class (if any) from caller class. And because of that you method is not getting called.